# Creating Subarray Without Copy and/or Allocation

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to C#, and am wondering how to do the following:

I create an array whose size of the maximum number of elements I will need to store:

```
int[] myArray = new int[64000];
```

I am passing this array to a 3rd party API.  In this API, they use the `.Length` property to determine the number of elements.  I don't want this to happen because the array length is the maximum count, not the "active count" (i.e. the number of elements in use).

With this in mind, is there a way to create another array, whose size equals the active count?  And, can this be done without a copy and/or allocation?  I already have the allocated memory -- all I want to do is indicate the subregion of interest while playing nicely with the 3rd party API.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using a `List` rather than an array, if you do not know exactly how many items will be in the collection.

Comment: What is the exact declaration of the API part (method?) that accepts your array?

Comment: I'm using Unity, and the what I'm doing is populating/managing vert/normal/tangent/uv/triangle arrays.  I want to have a pool of these arrays, where each array is a predetermined maximum size.  Then, as content comes/goes, the arrays become populated (not always to 100%), and I pass them off to an instance of UnityEngine.Mesh ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.html)).

Comment: To populate the arrays in UnityEngine.Mesh, I just assign an array reference.  There is no copy.  If I want to manage my own pools, I now have to allocate arrays that are the exact sizes, and let them get garbage collected.  This defeats the point of using these pools.  I would rather manage my own memory, but I'm not seeing many options here ...

Answer (score 5):

If the third party API accepts an `int[]`, the only way to pass your data in would be to copy.

An API could easily be designed where this isn't necessary (ie: pass the number of elements, or use `ArraySegment<T>`, etc), but if the API doesn't support it, a copy will be required.

Note that you can use [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.array.copy) to bulk-copy the items, however, instead of doing copying in a loop.